# How do I extract specific words from a text into another column (by looking at an external DF)

Tags: python, pandas, string, nlp, extract

I have scraped vacancies from Indeed, and these are two of the columns in my DataFrame:

```
        Location           Description
0       deventer  Hygiène Sécurité ...
1        hengelo  Supervisor Finan ...
2         zwolle  Compensations &  ...
```

28000 rows

I want to have another column that extracts the skills from the Description column, by looking at the dataframe that is shown below.

```
           soft_skill
0       communication
1  abstract reasoning
2   abstract thinking
```

930 rows

So ideally my new DF will look like this:

```
        Location           Description            Skills
0       deventer  Hygiène Sécurité ...     collaboration
1        hengelo  Supervisor Finan ...     communication
2         zwolle  Compensations &  ... critical thinking
```

28000 rows

Does anybody have an idea on how I could do this? I am also working on a ML/NER approach (using spacy), but I would first like to try this.

A complete and clean description looks like this, and the bold words should be extracted into a new column:

> hygiène sécurité environnement keolis netherlands has approximately 2100 employees with whom we jointly provide public transport in ijsselvecht utrecht twente and almere and on the train routes zutphenoldenzaal zwolleenschede and zwollekampen each year we transport 45 million passengers with 700 buses and 25 trains working from two intrinsic values clear and enterprising keolis nederland is a 100 subsidiary of the internationally operating mobility company keolis group which provides public transport in 16 countries with 68500 employees missions as a qhse manager at keolis netherlands you will focus on the creation of a safe and healthy workplace the safety and health of the employees as well as the safeguarding of the quality of service and its environmental friendliness in this role you will contribute to the various management systems keolis strives for environmental management system quality management system safety management system and the other standards keolis commits to thus contributing to the achievement of continuous improvement together with a team of 3 colleagues you will bring the awareness quality and compliance of all qhse aspects within the organization to a higher level there are challenges in the department to further professionalize including further development of the qhse policy design of the csr policy qhse awareness and prevention campaigns organization and management of qhse audits internal control and especially how do we secure this in the organization and keep all stakeholders connected and prepared a nice challenging position within an international mobility provider with nice colleagues why with about 2100 employees we are a large organization but we remain informal so you can easily walk in on colleagues for a chat but also for example to spar from our headquarters in deventer you will manage qhse profil a dynamic position in which no day is the same within an organization that is developing and to which you yourself can make an essential contribution we have excellent fringe benefits such as at least 27 days of vacation depending on age a yearend bonus and a wide range of online training courses we have an attractive lease scheme and we facilitate a phone and laptop there is plenty of room for personal development and contribution within an internationally operating mobility organization and last but not least the informal working atmosphere at our cosy office in deventer competencies which fit within keolis are **collaborating working together responsibility openness goodwill commitment relevant knowledge and experience** we see for the position a relevant completed education at hbo level towards qhse demonstrable experience in similar positions demonstrable experience in the substantive supervision and coaching of qhse employees knowledge and working in the english language is an advantage extensive and uptodate knowledge of relevant environmental and occupational health and safety laws and regulations knowledge of the applicable nen  vca and iso standards excellent advisory and communication skills work experience within public transport organizations is an advantage

Comment: are the skills names written in the `Description` column ? From where are you getting them ? can you please show whats in that column ? (a whole row as an example to know from where you want to get these skill names)

Comment: I added it into the text above, hope it clarifies it a bit

Comment: First thing is try to find a pattern within the descriptions that separates the skills from the rest of the text. Is there any?

Comment: the closest thing that I found and that might be useful for you is a library called `skillNet` that extracts skills from text, you work with that i guess. The drawback is that yiou cannot choose the skillsets you want (from the second database you mentionned). Here's their git repo : https://github.com/AnasAito/SkillNER